# ShareActionProvider Not Clickable

Tags: android

I want to call an activity after clicking on share icon in action bar. For this I
create a menu named 'flip' which contains an item named 'menu_share' for Android 
2.2+. Flip menu is inflated in 1st activity named `'ShareActivity'`. After this I want to call other activity after clicking on `shareicon` in action bar but icon not responding.

Code for menu xml file.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto=" >

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
          android:title="share"
          android:icon="@drawable/shar"
          yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
          yourapp:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
</menu>
```

Code for 1st activity.

```
public class ShareActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    SocialAuthAdapter adapter;
    EditText edit;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_share);

        ActionBar ab=getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new     ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.flip, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                super.onBackPressed();
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_share:
                startActivity(new Intent(this,ShActivity.class));
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have set an ActionProvider with `yourapp:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"`. This is likely intercepting the event, thus preventing your Activity from getting the call to `onOptionsItemSelected()`.

Since you want to start your own Activity instead of using Android's default share behavior, simply remove this line.

Comment: @Vishwajeet, I'm having a similar issue, except I want to use the default share behavior. When I add the ShareActionProvider, I can no longer click the share icon. any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @snapplex, I recommend creating a new question with relevant pieces of your code.

Comment: @snapplex I have the same problem. Did you open a question for this?

Comment: @snapplex I guess it is related to the ShareActionProvider maybe being mangled by Proguard. Do you use Proguard?